# How to return only first result hit from Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

If we want to use Google Drive with GoogleDriva Android API we forst make a query to retrieve all the files that meet our criteria. Multiple file can have the same name as names are not unique identifiers. DriveId's are. But sometimes we are interested only in the latest file. The usual way (from google web site) is something like this.

```
void retrieveFiles() {
    SortOrder sortOrder = new SortOrder.Builder()
        .addSortDescending(SortableField.MODIFIED_DATE)
        .build();
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, filename), "my_filename.txt"))
        .setSortOrder(sortOrder)
        .build();
    MetadataBufferResult mbr = Drive.DriveApi.query(query).await().getMetadataBuffer();

    // Now we can iterate through all the result hits
    Metadata metadata;
    Iterator<Metadata> iterator = mbr.getMetadataBuffer().iterator();
    metadata = iterator.next();  // get the first hit
});
```

This query returns metadata for all files that meet criteria. But, it would be useful to limit the search only to the first file (or arbitrary number of them) since this is teh one we are interested. Sorting enables us to prune the result.
Is there a way to limit the result set to? Somethinh like TOP N ROWS in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can set pageSize to limit the number of rows returned to 1.

There is no way to do a group by or a distinct like you would in SQL.  If you have files with the same name your going to get them all.

The only thing I can think of would be to add an orderBy

> [orderBy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list)  string  
> A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are
>   'createdTime', 'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name',
>   'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and
>   'viewedByMeTime'. Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be
>   reversed with the 'desc' modifier. Example usage:
>   ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name. Please note that there is a
>   current limitation for users with approximately one million files in
>   which the requested sort order is ignored.

Then sort by 'modifiedTime' which you appear to be doing already.  You can then then you can just deal with the duplicates locally.